# Check if all lines in a file are same

Tags: shell-script, shell, awk, sed

If the following file contains same content in all line it should print "contents are same".

```
$ cat file
  example-line
  example-line
  example-line
```

If any of the line differs from others, then it should print "contents are different"

e.g.

```
$ cat file
  example-line
  somethingelse
  example-line
```

will print "contents are different".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`. Map the key names in the array `unique` and by the time the entire file processing is complete, the array should have just one key.

```
awk '!unique[$0]++ { count++ } END { print count == 1 ? "contents are same" : "contents are different"  }' file
```

The general syntax for `awk` is a pattern-action model.

```
pattern { action }
```

The part `!unique[$0]++` creates a hash map (associative array) by creating the key as the content of the whole line `$0`.  When the first time an unique line is seen, the value for `unique['<key-name>']` will be zero, and the `!` block negates this false and becomes a true action for the `{..}` part where we increment a counter.

Since we also do a post-increment on the value, for subsequent occurrences of the same line, the negation will produce a boolean false condition causing the `{..}` block to be not executed. The instructions within `END` are executed after all the lines are processed. Since we just have one key in the array at the end of the processing, we declare the lines are same.

Comment: It works as expected. if possible, can you explain this please?

Comment: Why is this downvoted? When it has a well explained content?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I am not sure who downvoted this, this awk script works great to me.

Comment: @smc When you post an incomplete (e.g.one without an attempted solution like yours) it usually gets downvotes and often the answers get downvoted too for "encouraging" people to post incomplete questions. So idk but maybe it's that?

Answer (score 6):

Using `uniq`:

`uniq -c testfile | [ $(wc -l) -eq 1 ] && echo 'contents  are the same' || echo 'contents  are different'`

Comment: This.  The core unix tools are very powerful and may save time.

Comment: Note that this would print `... different` if the file can't be found or can't be read.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do the comparison concisely, portably and efficiently is:

```
awk '!seen[$0]++ && NR>1{exit 1}'
```

For example and with output messages added:

```
$ cat file1
  example-line
  example-line
  example-line

$ cat file2
  example-line
  somethingelse
  example-line

$ awk '!seen[$0]++ && NR>1{f=1; exit} END{print "contents are " (f ? "different" : "same"); exit f}' file1
contents are same
$ echo $?
0

$ awk '!seen[$0]++ && NR>1{f=1; exit} END{print "contents are " (f ? "different" : "same"); exit f}' file2
contents are different
$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: perfect, should be the accepted answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Tried with below awk solution and it worked fine

command

```
i=`awk '{if (!seen[$0]++){print $0}}' filename| wc -l`



if [[ $i == 1 ]]; then echo "contents are same"; else echo "contents are different"; fi
```